# creating link dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am making an app based on Google maps. Now the user enters some locations. I want to create a link which has all the locations entered by the user. The user has a limit of 10 locations.

Now i want to create a dynamically to request Google for distances between that locations.
How to create the link dynimacally when i don't know how many locations has user entered.

here is the basic link for two locations in Google's documentation:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

which gives:

Vancouver to San Francisco  Vancouver to Victoria
Seattle to San Francisco    Seattle to Victoria

now if i have many inputs, how to create this link dynamically using javascript ?

thanks
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to use the distanceMatrix class from the google maps api which takes js object and handles the request passing the result to a callback.

modified version of google example:

```
var origins = ["Vancouver BC", "Seattle"];
var destinations = ["San Francisco", "Victoria BC"];
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins: [origins],
    destinations: [destinations],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING,
}, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
// Response contains the same object as the one from the link
}
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Answer (score 0):

The url parameters seem to consist of the following elements:

```
// Url,
# http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?

// Origin locations:
# origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle
// Destinations:
# &destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC
// (And some additional options:)
# &mode=bicycling
# &language=fr-FR
# &sensor=false
```

Now, if you have 2 arrays with locations, the url is pretty simple to build:

```
var origins = ["Vancouver BC", "Seattle"];
var destinations = ["San Francisco", "Victoria BC"];

var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"+
    "origins=" +
    origins.join('|').replace(/ /g,'+') +
    "&destinations=" +
    destinations.join('|').replace(/ /g,'+') +
    "&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false";
```

`.join('|')` joins the array elements together with a pipeline (`|`) character in between, so `origins.join('|')` returns `"Vancouver BC|Seattle"`.
Then, `.replace(/ /g,'+')` replaces all spaces in the string with plus (`+`) signs.

You can add as many locations as you want to these arrays.